# Multiple ng-models on one input field?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

I have a form, and a list of items. 
I used `ng-model="searchFor"` to filter out the list of items appropriately (this part is working fine), but I also want to "submit" the item that's filtered out -- which would require `ng-model="adding_item.name"` on the input field as well (I think).

Can you have multiple `ng-models` on one input field? 
Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 15):

Try using ng-change event to capture model value and assign it to other input element with its own ng-model.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="input" ng-change="input1=input;input2=input; " />
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="input1" />
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="input2" />
  <br>Model
  <br>{{input | uppercase}}
  <br>Model 1
  <br>{{input1 | uppercase}}
  <br>Model 2
  <br>{{input2 | uppercase}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

No,  ngModel wasn't supposed to do things like this, at this point it is better to start relocating the logic from the view. For this scenario you could make use of `getterSetter` option:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#binding-to-a-getter-setter

It is hard to make substantial suggestions without seeing the code.