# How to use more than two ng-model in one input field

Tags: angularjs, html, checkbox

Is it possible to have more than one ng-model on one input field ?

e.g: 
`<input ng-model="formData.glCode" ng-model="accNumber" ng-change="accNumber = editAccountNumber(accNumber)"/>`

Because all inputs where I want to apply this have ng-model set already and I also need to edit model name `ng-model="accNumber"`

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448097/multiple-ng-models-on-one-input-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind 2 models to one input field in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890331/how-to-bind-2-models-to-one-input-field-in-angular)

Answer (score 3):

If you can't edit the input and you are trying to bind the model to the controller use the same model which already exist on the input:

```
<input ng-model="formData.glCode" ng-change="formData.glCode = editAccountNumber(formData.glCode)"/>
```

Possible duplicate:
[How to bind 2 models to one input field in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890331/how-to-bind-2-models-to-one-input-field-in-angular)

Comment: Thanks Mohamad, that does exactly what i want

Comment: Can you please consider checking the answer as correct if the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

No, **`ngModel`** wasn't supposed to do things like this, at this point it is better to start relocating the logic from the view. For this scenario you could make use of **`$watch`** and get the `accNumber` value in controller.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('formData.glCode', function(){
        console.log($scope.accNumber);
    });
    $scope.editAccountNumber = function(glCode) {
      return glCode;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" 
       ng-model="formData.glCode"
       ng-change="accNumber = editAccountNumber(formData.glCode)"/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code: `ng-model-options`

```
    <input ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

for more detail you can try this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-model-options.asp

Comment: That has nothing to do with multiple ng-models